# How to convert HTML to RTF in UWP

Tags: html, uwp, html-agility-pack, richtextblock

I want to convert HTML to RichTextBlock in UWP. I found some answers in stackoverflow tried the code in following link

[link](https://github.com/xleon/HTML2XAML)

But when I try to bind html property in richtextblock controls it gives error saying The name "Properties" does not exist in the namespace "using XAMLHtml"

I included following code to convert HTML to RTF in XAMLHtml.cs file

```
class XAMLHtml
{
    public class HtmlProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Html",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(HtmlProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, HtmlChanged));

        private static RichTextBlock _currentObject;

        private static void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var richText = d as RichTextBlock;
            if (richText == null) return;

            _currentObject = richText;

            //Generate blocks
            var xhtml = e.NewValue as string;
            var blocks = GenerateBlocksForHtml(xhtml);

            _currentObject = null;

            //Add the blocks to the RichTextBlock
            richText.Blocks.Clear();
            foreach (var b in blocks)
                richText.Blocks.Add(b);
        }

        private static List<Block> GenerateBlocksForHtml(string xhtml)
        {
            var blocks = new List<Block>();

            try
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(xhtml);

                var block = GenerateParagraph(doc.DocumentNode);
                blocks.Add(block);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return blocks;
        }

        // TODO this method seams to be removing necessary spaces in #text nodes
        private static string CleanText(string input)
        {
            var clean = Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(input);
            //clean = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(clean);
            if (clean == "\0")
                clean = "\n";
            return clean;
        }

        private static Block GenerateBlockForTopNode(HtmlNode node)
            => GenerateParagraph(node);


        private static void AddChildren(Paragraph p, HtmlNode node)
        {
            var added = false;
            foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                var i = GenerateBlockForNode(child);
                if (i != null)
                {
                    p.Inlines.Add(i);
                    added = true;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
            {
                p.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) });
            }
        }

        private static void AddChildren(Span s, HtmlNode node)
        {
            var added = false;

            foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                var i = GenerateBlockForNode(child);
                if (i != null)
                {
                    s.Inlines.Add(i);
                    added = true;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
            {
                s.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) });
            }
        }

        private static Inline GenerateBlockForNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            switch (node.Name)
            {


                case "b":
                case "B":
                case "strong":
                case "STRONG":
                    return GenerateBold(node);
                case "i":
                case "I":
                case "em":
                case "EM":
                    return GenerateItalic(node);
                case "u":
                case "U":
                    return GenerateUnderline(node);
                case "br":
                case "BR":
                    return new LineBreak();                                          
                default:
                    return GenerateSpanWNewLine(node);
            }

        }

        private static Inline GenerateBold(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var bold = new Bold();
            AddChildren(bold, node);
            return bold;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateUnderline(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var underline = new Underline();
            AddChildren(underline, node);
            return underline;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateItalic(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var italic = new Italic();
            AddChildren(italic, node);
            return italic;
        }

        private static Block GenerateParagraph(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            AddChildren(paragraph, node);
            return paragraph;
        }


        private static Inline GenerateSpanWNewLine(HtmlNode node)
        {
            var span = new Span();
            AddChildren(span, node);
            if (span.Inlines.Count > 0)
                span.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return span;
        }

    }
}
```

here what I write in xaml file

```
<Page
x:Class="SampleHtml.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
xmlns:converter="using XAMLHtml" 
xmlns:html="using HTMLPage1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"   
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBlock converter:Properties.Html="{Binding HTMLPage1}" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

here is the code in html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
    <p><i>This text is italic</i></p>
    <p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate.Thank you

Comment: Please share the code that you have written.

Comment: I edited the post and add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project is class lib for UWP platform. please download the full project and refer it.

I check the code the class name is `HtmlProperties` but not `Properties`, so you need edit your xaml code like the following

```
<RichTextBlock converter:HtmlProperties.Html="{x:Bind HtmlString}" />
```

In general we could use `WebViewBrush` to get the webview content then set it the  Rectangle control. for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush).

Comment: I changed it to HtmlProperties and tried the both ways but it still gives that error.this the screen shot of my file structure         https://imgur.com/vBNLxKX

Comment: I downloaded your code and installed the Html2Xaml package.But it still shows this error.do I have to change anything?

Comment: when I didn't install html2xaml package it gives error for richtextblock saying The property "Children" does not have an accessible setter.And also the above error which is, The name "Properties" does not exist in the namespace "using:HtmlToRtf.WinRT_RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml" is still there.

Comment: It seems like html2xaml package doesn't support <ol><ul><sup><sub> html elements..Is there a way to make it work?